# Google Maps API v3 polyline. How to extend mouseover area?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm using the Google Maps API to render a map with a route from point A to point B.
To draw to route, I used a **google.maps.Polyline** object.
What I would like to do now is adding some info **google.maps.InfoWindow** when the user move his mouse over the line and hide it when he leaves.

The problem is that the line seems to be only one pixel thin to I'm constantly losing the focus.

Any thoughts about how I could handle it to keep my box open when moving the cursor?

Thx

Comment: Make a thicker line?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it. The problem is that to have the correct width for my focus, I would have to draw a line 15 pixels wide which wouldn't be aesthetic at all.
Is there any way to make my object is wider that it looks?

Comment: Using a setTimeOut or SetInterval in mouseout event? to hide the infobox every X sec?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create 2 lines with the same path:

**Line#1:** your line as it currently is, but set `clickable` to `false`

**Line#2:** your line as it currently is, but set `strokeWeight` to `15` and `strokeOpacity` to `0.001`

Apply your `mouseover`-handler to Line#2

Line#2 will not be visible(because of the `strokeOpacity`), but will still respond to mouse-events